# Fit curve to a region with specific color in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a curve on a specific area in an image using the color of the pixels. As it is shown in the image (https://db.tt/PcxHGbT3), there is a region in the image with grey color that can be detected using image processing in Matlab. Once I found the position of the pixels using the following code in Matlab:

```
im = imread('layer.jpg');
figure,imshow(im);title('Original Image');
[y,x] = find(all(im<100, 3));
```

I need to find the position of the points sitting on the central line of the region which is shown in the image (https://db.tt/PcxHGbT3). I was thinking to somehow fit a curve, but I have no idea on how I can do this in Matlab. Is there any shorter way other than processing all of the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [im2bw](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html)(im, 100/256) to threshold the image and [bwmorph](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html)(BW, 'thin', INF) to thin the result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But then no matter how thin it would be result, still there would be several pixels thin. How can I find just the center points?

Comment: If you pass Inf to the thin operation, the result should be just one pixel wide. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I tried this an here is the result: https://db.tt/wpYa8Keg - as you see, there are some extra lines at both ends. Should I manually remove them? or is there any better way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use matlab binary image operations to get centroids of the points withing the gray area. Having centroids you can do whatever with them, e.g. fitting lines. This is one  example based on your image, how this can be done.

```
% convert rgb to gray scale
im = rgb2gray(imread('layer.jpg'));

% mask of gray-color with points
bwMask1 = im < 100; 

% mask with points only
bwMask2 = im < 20;  

% remove points outside gray area
bwMask3 = bwareaopen(bwMask1, 400);

% points only withing gray ![enter image description here][1]area
bwMask4 = bwMask2 & ~(bwMask3 - bwMask2);

% label all points
[L] = bwlabel(bwMask4, 8);

% calculate points parameters
pointStats = regionprops(L);

% get centroids of each point
pointCentroidsCell = {pointStats(:).Centroid};
pointCentroidsMat  = vertcat(pointCentroidsCell{:});


%plot results:
RGB = label2rgb(L); 
figure, imshow(RGB); title('labeled points');
![enter image description here][2]
figure,imshow(im); hold on;
plot(pointCentroidsMat(:, 1), pointCentroidsMat(:, 2), 'r*');
title('Found centroinds');
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried your code on this image: https://db.tt/Z1za9o1L but it doesn't work. Could you please double check it?

Comment: @user114781 It doesn't work because there are no points on it. In both examples you provided in your question there are points. So I guess, normally there are no points at all?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Those points in the image are the points that I am looking to find. I just showed them to clarify that I al looking for the center line of the region. Generally all of the photos are in for of https://db.tt/Z1za9o1L. Please let me know if you can suggest any other solution.